# PTIJ: Public toilets laxatives and hypnotics against hashgacha pratit

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Megila 5. 10

> וַיִּתְאַפַּק הָמָן, וַיָּבוֹא אֶל-בֵּיתוֹ

6.1.

> בַּלַּיְלָה הַהוּא, נָדְדָה שְׁנַת הַמֶּלֶךְ

Haman was forced to restrain himself from going to the toilet. He managed to do it but had to go to his house.

Achasverosh had insomnia.

We see that Haman did not take laxatives, Hachashverosh didn't take hypnotics, and there were no public toilets.

We have a remez of prohibition for those three practices in verses. How did Rabbis not protest against the spreading of modern practices concerning laxatives, hypnotics and public toilets?  If we need a new geula, knowing that Masse Avot siman Labanim, how can it occur?

Please provide source to melamed zchut the modern Jewish minhagim which  apparently break minhag neviim.

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: This is a perfect example of what I've been complaining about [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5018/). If you don't think the joke is funny, downvote and move on. This isn't close-worthy: it's distinctly Purim, distinctly Torah, and distinctly Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed we find in Divrei Hayamim ([1:25:1](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.25.1)) that Haman was a Navi:

> וַיַּבְדֵּ֣ל דָּוִיד֩ וְשָׂרֵ֨י הַצָּבָ֜א לַעֲבֹדָ֗ה לִבְנֵ֤י אָסָף֙ וְהֵימָ֣ן וִֽידוּת֔וּן הנביאים [הַֽנִּבְּאִ֛ים] בְּכִנֹּר֥וֹת בִּנְבָלִ֖ים וּבִמְצִלְתָּ֑יִם וַֽיְהִי֙ מִסְפָּרָ֔ם אַנְשֵׁ֥י מְלָאכָ֖ה לַעֲבֹדָתָֽם׃
>
> David and the officers of the army set apart for service the sons of Asaph, of Haman, and of Jeduthun, who were Nevi’im to the accompaniment of lyres, harps, and cymbals. The list of men who performed this work, according to their service, was:

However, the Talmud ([Chagiga 10b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah_10b.10))  provides proper outlook:

> ומאי כהררין התלויין בשערה דברי תורה מדברי קבלה לא ילפינן:
>
> The Gemara asks: And in light of this verbal analogy, in what way is this halakha like mountains suspended by a hair? The Gemara answers: The textual evidence is not that strong, as generally one does not derive Torah matters from texts of the tradition, i.e., Prophets and Writings. Since the prophets were not permitted to introduce new halakhot, as the Torah is the only authoritative source in that regard, this verbal analogy does not carry the same weight as a halakha derived from the Torah itself.

Thus we may indeed use laxatives among other practices.

Answer (score 1):

regarding public toilets, it is עת לעשות לה' הפרו תורתך because Gedole Israel said that Lithuanian community needs a Journal, and created the Yated Neeman, so after the diffusion of the Yated, in the Machane Litai, we can use Yated in the city, despite that Tora allowed it only out of the Machane.

> (יד) וְיָתֵ֛ד תִּֽהְיֶ֥ה לְךָ֖ עַל־אֲזֵנֶ֑ךָ וְהָיָה֙ בְּשִׁבְתְּךָ֣ ח֔וּץ וְחָֽפַרְתָּ֣ה בָ֔הּ וְשַׁבְתָּ֖ וְכִסִּ֥יתָ אֶת־צֵֽאָתֶֽךָ׃

So since the creation of the Yated we have public toilets in the city.

Regarding laxatives may be that since Jewish people speak Yidish, they use שמן קיק that was not useful because the mishna says:

> ולא בשמן קיק

When people are hungry they say "Geeb A keek!", and by homonymy, the use of oil of keek, a potent laxative is largely taken. But it is a mistake.

Regarding hypnotics, this is a new Mitsva that appeared after the nes of Purim, חייב איניש לבשומי בפוריא עד דלא ידע בין ארור המן לברוך מרדכי. Most poskim explain that the mitsva is fulfilled when you sleep as a result alcohol drinking. Following those poskim, you can take an hypnotic. It is less expensive than a good whisky and have a faster action.